# Get biblatex-apa to truncate names starting on the first citation

Tags: biblatex

I'm pretty sure that my question is specific to the `biblatex-apa` package.

Let me start with my minimum working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{foo,
    Author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
    Address = {City}, Publisher = {Publisher}, Title = {Title}, Year = {2015}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
The APA standard says that the first citation with 3--5 authors should have the author list in full, like so: \autocite{foo}.

Subsequent citations are truncated according to their disambiguation rules \autocite{foo}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the minimum working example]

And looking at `apa.cbx`, it appears that a lot of effort went into producing this behavior!

So I feel a little bad asking: is there a way to disable this? I want an APA-like citation format that always behaves like the 2nd (and subsequent) citations.

Some ideas I had:

- Is there an easy way to manipulate the citation tracker (or whatever mechanism is used to determine whether it is the first or a subsequent citation)?
- The first citation still truncates if there are more than 5 authors. Can this setting be adjusted? It does not appear to respond to `maxnames` or `maxcitenames`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real way to change this as it wouldn't be APA style and it's largely hard-coded. You could just re-declare the whole name format for labelname using `\DeclareNameFormat` as you like though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the approach that @PLK suggested. For future reference, here is the implementation. Place this after loading biblatex with the apa style:

```
% Hack to make biblatex-apa truncate names on all citations, even though the
% APA style says to include the full author list (up to 5) on the first
% citation.
% This is copied from apa.cbx in the biblatex-apa package, and modified to
% remove the \ifciteseen test
\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}
    {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
       {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
       {}%
     \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
       {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
         {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
         {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}%
       {}%
     \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
       {\relax}%
       {}%
     }%
  }
\makeatother
```